# Resetting a variable from another class

Tags: java, android

So, i'm importing a few variables from another class.`flag  = Quiz1.flag;`

```
flag2 = Quiz2.flag;
flag3 = Quiz3.flag;
flag4 = Quiz4.flag;
flag5 = Quiz5.flag;
flag6 = Quiz6.flag;
flag7 = Quiz7.flag;
flag8 = Quiz8.flag;
flag9 = Quiz9.flag;
flag10= Quiz10.flag;`
```

The problem is that once the `Activity` is repeated, the flag values keep accumulating, instead of having only 1 flag in a value different to 0.

How can i change the value of for example `flag2` on `Quiz2` back to `0` once the `Activity` is over?

Comment: You need to show more code to understand where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all of your flags are declared as static in Quiz, when you modify flag, you are modifying the single original in the Quiz. Stop using static.

If you insist on using static, then you would set the flag back something like:

```
Quiz2.flag = 0;
```

Comment: That method is exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much sir.